# railsでのeager_loadの結合条件の追加はできますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在、railsを利用し、Facebookのような投稿に対しユーザーが「いいね」を押すようなWEBアプリを作成しています。

テーブルとmodelは以下の3つで構成しています。

- Post　id[PK], user_id, text
- User　id[PK], name
- Good　id[PK], post_id, user_id

POSTの一覧ページにて、自分が「いいね」を押しているか判るようにしたいので、
以下のようなSQLをクエリで発行したいのですが

> SELECT * FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN goods
>   ON goods.post_id = posts.id AND goods.user_id = 3

現状の実装の

```
@posts = Post.eager_load(:goods).where(goods: {user_id: 3})
```

では、

> SELECT * FROM `posts`
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN `goods` ON `goods`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
>   WHERE `goods`.`user_id` = 3

となってしまい、思ったとおりのクエリが発行できません。

```
@posts = Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN goods ON posts.id = goods.post_id AND goods.user_id = 3")
```

とすれば、発行自体は出来るのですが、今度はキャッシュが聞かない為、viewでクエリが別途発行され、あまり良い方法ではないなと感じています。

eager_loadにjoinsのような条件を渡せれば良いのですが、そういった方法はありませんか？
また、relationの張り方を工夫すれば問題ないなどという事であればご教示お願いします。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: rails のバージョンは、どれでしょうか? 美しくはありませんが、`Post.eager_load(:goods).joins("AND goods.user_id = 3").to_sql` でも行ける気がするので。

Comment: railsのバージョンは4.2.4になります。
ご提案いただいた方法で無事、思ったとおりのクエリが発行できました。
joinsで条件追加ができるとは知りませんでした。
本当に困っていたので助かりました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: 前提として、 where で left join されるテーブルの条件があると、 null のカラムが含まれるとその条件は自動的に不成立とみなされ、実質 inner join と同じ結果になってしまうのですね。 (そして、その実、 DB エンジンは大体そのような最適化を行う。)

Answer (score 1):

(コメントより)

rails のバージョンによっては、美しくはありませんが、

```
Post.eager_load(:goods).joins("AND goods.user_id = 3").to_sql
```

でも行ける気がします。

Comment: 補足として、手元でそれっぽく動いていることを確認しました @ rails 5